# como puedo mover un svg en el centro de un boton - react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap

Quiero mover al centro del boton el svg y que sea resposive, ya lo intenté pero no he podido. Estoy usando react y bootstrap.

React

```
function PlayButton(props) {
return (
  <Button variant="primary" className="play">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="playlogo h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
    <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z" clipRule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
  </Button>
);
 }
```

CSS

```
   .play{
  width: 40%;
  height: 8%;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.playlogo{
  width: 33%;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Se ve así

[image: Se ve así]

Quiero que quede algo asi, el problema es que si lo hago moviendolo de posición cuando lo paso a móvil no queda bien.

[image: quiero]

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que utilizas flexbox o grid.
Con flexbox sería algo así :

```
display:flex
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
```

Comment: ya lo habia intentado, pero se queda igual.